# select 2 no funciona en modal

Tags: javascript

buenas tengo un select y quiero usar el `select2` entonces en la ventana modal no me esta funcionando por ejemplo me salen los datos pero no busca ni se pone el cursor en el buscador ni nada pero si toma el estilo, si lo quito del modal y lo pongo en body busca y todo bien.

llamo la libreria de esta manera

```
    <script src="../public/js/selects/select2.min.js"></script>


<script >

// Select with search
          $('.select-search').select2();


</script>
```

y este seria el select2

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Categoria:</label>
                <select name="id_categoria" id="id_categoria" class="form-control select-search" data-fouc>
                  <option  value="">Seleccione una Categoria</option>
                    <?php

                       for($i=0; $i<sizeof($cat);$i++){

                         ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $cat[$i]["id_categoria"]?>"><?php echo $cat[$i]["categoria"];?></option>
                         <?php
                       }
                    ?>
                </select>
              </div>
```

quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal para que en le modal no funcione y fuera del modal si funcione

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Hola a mí me funcionó agregando lo siguiente:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
        dropdownParent: $('#myModal .modal-body')
    });
```

Esto lo leí en [aquí](https://rilaros.blogspot.com/2020/06/select2-no-funciona-correctamente-en-un.html)

Answer (score 1):

yo tuve el mismo problema, y la solución es muy sencilla... En la modal tienes esto:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Este es el div con el que comienza tu modal ¿verdad?

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es quitar el `tabindex="-1"` de modo que te quede de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalExample" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Con eso ya deberia dejarte escribir y usar el buscador.

Ahora si con eso aun no te funciona, veo que donde inicializas select2 no lo haces cuando termine de cargar el DOM, ¿Estas utlizando la libreria de jquery?

En cualquier caso te dejo aqui la prueba sin el tabIndex

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select').select2(); 
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" id="btnAbrirAgregarBien" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalExample">
          ABRIR MODAL
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalExample" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ejemplo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="frmAgregarBienCapitalizable">         
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label>Ejemplo:</label>
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="select" id="select">
                              <option value="0">Seleccionar propietario</option>                          
                              <option value="1"> CARRO</option>                          
                              <option value="2">MOTO</option>
                              <option value="2">CAMION</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                  
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">
              
                    SIP
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Perfecto, me funciono asi, gracias

Answer (score 0):

No funciona, porque cuando abres el modal, tu select no se encuentra definido.

Para que funcione, debes definir el select2 después de invocar al modal.

Por ejemplo, si presionando un boton abres el modal, ahí deberías definir el select2:

```
$('button#open-modal').click(function(){
    $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    $('.select-search').select2();
});
```